# ngFor en angular html

Tags: angular, bootstrap

Tengo un ngFor para mostrar los elementos de un array de objetos en unas grillas de html y bootstrap, pero lo muestra desordenado.

Resultado actual:
[image: current result]

Resultado esperado:
[image: expected result]

Aqui mi [codigo](https://codesandbox.io/s/aling-ngfor-pm54df?file=/src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: está medio raro, tienes un arreglo plano y quieres hacer lo siguiente: row1 "Labor"
row2 "Part" "IGST" "CGST"
row3 "SGST"
Dicho de otra forma iterar sobre un array, si es index 0 va a row 1, si es index 1 2 y 3 va a row 2 y si es index 4 va a row 3, lo que yo haría sería armar una estructura nueva como por ejemplo `rows: [[{
      code: "Labor",
      costAmount: 150
    }], [
    {
      code: "IGST",
      costAmount: 572.75
    }],[{
      code: "SGST",
      costAmount: 0
    }]]`

Comment: con esta estructura nueva te sería muy fácil hacer lo que quieres

Comment: @LPZadkiel Hola ya lo intenté y ahora ya no se ve nada